# Image pixelates during transition css

Tags: image, css, rendering, css-transitions

```js
  $('.click').click(function(){
     $('.image').toggleClass("image1");
  });
```

```css
  .click{
    position:absolute;
    top:1%;
    left:45%;
    cursor:pointer;
  }
  .image{
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top:25%;
    left:0%;
    height:60%;
    -webkit-transition: all 3s ease;  
    -moz-transition: all 3s ease;  
    -o-transition: all 3s ease;  
    -ms-transition: all 3s ease;  
    transition: all 3s ease;
  }
  .image1{
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top:25%;
    left:50%;
    height:50%;
   -webkit-transition: all 3s ease;  
    -moz-transition: all 3s ease;  
    -o-transition: all 3s ease;  
    -ms-transition: all 3s ease;  
    transition: all 3s ease;
  }
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div class="click">Click here to animate</div>
  <img class="image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/Winter_baby_10-months-old.jpg">
```

I've noticed that if there's an image that goes under a transition, it would pixelate during the process until the animation is completed.

how can this be avoided?

Comment: can you please make fiddle or SO snippet?

Comment: Sure thing @sagarkodte

Answer (score 0):

You can use `image-rendering: pixelated;` to image. Hope you are ok with it. Thanks.

```js
$('.click').click(function(){
     $('.image').toggleClass("image1");
  });
```

```css
.click{
    position:absolute;
    top:1%;
    left:45%;
    cursor:pointer;
  }
  .image{
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top:25%;
    left:0%;
    height:60%;
    -webkit-transition: all 3s ease;  
    -moz-transition: all 3s ease;  
    -o-transition: all 3s ease;  
    -ms-transition: all 3s ease;  
    transition: all 3s ease;
    image-rendering: pixelated;
  }
  .image1{
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top:25%;
    left:50%;
    height:50%;
   -webkit-transition: all 3s ease;  
    -moz-transition: all 3s ease;  
    -o-transition: all 3s ease;  
    -ms-transition: all 3s ease;  
    transition: all 3s ease;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div class="click">Click here to animate</div>
  <img class="image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/Winter_baby_10-months-old.jpg">
```

Comment: Yeah, I considered that but that would just pixelate the image the whole time since the images are being resized or scaled.

Comment: I believed it remained the same, I think you can appreciate the effect it does better on chrome